# Should i keep different dimens file for different screen sizes or different screen densities?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing my first android app and want the app to run on Mobiles and tablets only in portrait mode. I developed the app using Moto G4 plus (1920x1080, 401 ppi) but it looks different on small screen devices.

I read many documentation from android developer documentation but still not clear as to how should I provide alternative resources for different screen sizes.

My app looks very different on 5.5 inch and 4 inch devices.
So should I have different values folder for different screen sizes like small,medium,large or for different densities like ldpi,hdpi etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for better UI, you need to provide different layouts for different screen sizes
You need to create multiple layout xmls and put in res folder as belew:

```
res/layout/your_layout.xml             (layout for normal screen)
res/layout-small/your_layout.xml       (layout for small screen)
res/layout-large/your_layout.xml       (layout for large screen)
res/layout-xlarge/your_layout.xml      (layout for extra large screen)
```

Similarly, you need to have multiple images:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/your_icon.png        (image for medium density)
res/drawable-hdpi/your_icon.png        (image for high density)
res/drawable-xhdpi/your_icon.png       (image for extra high density)
res/drawable-xxhdpi/your_icon.png       (image for extra extra high density)
res/drawable-xxxhdpi/your_icon.png
```

Find more details on below links:
Official doc:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Tutorials:
http://mrbool.com/how-to-handle-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android/31291
http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html